# Angular Routing isn't being intercepted

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have the following in my app.js file:

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services


  var APP = angular.module('DiagsDashboard', ['ngRoute', 'DiagsDashboard.filters', 
'DiagsDashboard.services', 'DiagsDashboard.directives', 'DiagsDashboard.controllers']);

APP.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: '/views/shared/Error.html' })
        .when('/Error', { templateUrl: '/views/shared/Error.html' })
        .when('/Diagsdashboard', { templateUrl: '/views/shared/Error.html' })
        .when('/Diagsdashboard/Error', { templateUrl: '/views/shared/Error.html' })
        .otherwise({ templateUrl: '/views/shared/Error.html' });
});
```

But when I browse to:

```
- /localhost/#
- /localhost/#/DiagsDashboard/
- /localhost/#/DiagsDashboard/Error
- /localhost/#/error
```

The whole page re-loads and everything refreshes. 
I've copied this code from a project where it works and I have angular-route.js included.

This is an MVC application located within IIS as a sub-application at **/localhost/DiagsDashboard**.

Comment: You have html5Mode set to true, which means that the `#` is not needed

Comment: I think you should browse to /localhost/#!, since you have the `hashPrefix` set to `!`.

Comment: I get http 403 (forbidden) if I use browser to: http://localhost:63599/#!/diagsdashboard/

Comment: Regardless of # or !# I receive the 403 message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was simply I hadn't give ng-app a name in the markup. I'd read that it is possible to use ng-app without a name but obviously that isn't the case.